# How to convert point cloud without RGB field to depth image?

Tags: ros, depth-image-proc, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte

I want to convert sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 message to sensor_msgs::Image and the point cloud does not have the RGB field. It only has X Y Z fields.

I saw the CloudtoImage tutorial and when I tried to run it needs the RGB field, or else its resulting in error.

The point cloud is from kinect and I saw depth_img_proc nodelet which uses the camera parameters to convert the depth image to point cloud.

I want something which exactly does opposite to that using the camera parameters.

Is there anything which is already implemented ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63741/how-to-convert-point-cloud-without-rgb-field-to-depth-image-?/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-05-28**:
how are u getting the point cloud, are u using a kinect, or stereo-vision? Because you can usually get both. PointCloud2 is coloured and point cloud is uncoloured

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-28**:
I get the kinect point cloud, then extract some keypoints of PointXYZ using PCL. Now I want to get the corresponding u,v positions on the depth image of the original pointcloud. Thus I converted the PCL PointXYZ to sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 .I m struck on how to find corresponding u,v on depth image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have the depth image already... why don't you just use that, and then calculate the X and Y coordinates yourself from the camera parameters.

X = (columns from center) * depth / focal_length

Y = (rows from center) * depth / focal_length

You can either store the camera focal length in your program, or retrieve it from the /camera_info topic.

---

Originally posted by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) with karma: 100 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0